# Can you help me with this?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to derive closed formula of solution:

S= $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{7}-1}\right)+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{7}-1}\right)^2+...+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{7}-1}\right)^{x+1}$

I can't figure it out because final term is ^(x+1).

Comment: Sum of geometric series.

Comment: Do you know what geometric progression is?

Comment: Whenever someone says "step by step", it makes me think they don't want to put in any effort.  $S$ is a geometric series, so use the closed form for it's sum.  Then stick it in the limit, which is just the ration of polynomials.   Why do you need steps, when it's the big ideas that are the problem?

Comment: From one Blue to another: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3504518/edit) to add details.

Comment: @B. Goddard How do I transform it to the closed form when my final term is x+1?Can't figure that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometric series is
$1 + a + a^{2} + \cdots + a^{n} = \frac{a^{n+1}}{a-1}$ then take $a = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1} {\sqrt{7}-1} $ and $n = x +1$ in the geometric series.